# Styling an SVG line with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is there any way to style an `SVG` line with `CSS`? I have tried adding. I want to add classes `onclick` with `JQuery` later on. This will add the `class`, then change the stroke colour.

```
.black {
  fill: black!important;
  stroke: black!important;
}
```

to my `SVG`

```
<g id="Layer_1">
        <image display="none" overflow="visible" width="1800" height="4913" xlink:href="../../../../Desktop/gcs-career-path.jpg"  transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -405.5005 -428.001)"></image>
        <polyline class="black" fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="546.834,107.001 550.723,105.249 641.501,64.334"/>
        <line class="black" fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="641.501" y1="151" x2="551.168" y2="109.667"/>
        <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="646.834" y1="151" x2="739.834" y2="108.001"/>
        <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="646.834" y1="64.334" x2="739.834" y2="105.5"/>
        <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="746.168" y1="105.5" x2="840.834" y2="77.997"/>
        <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="848.166" y1="77.997" x2="943.833" y2="97.667"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

I have modified/simplified your example in this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o7dqejL0/5/), so you can try it.

Where **HTML** is:

```
<button>
add class
</button>
<svg width="1050" height="355">
    <polyline fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="546.834,107.001 550.723,105.249 641.501,64.334"/>
    <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="641.501" y1="151" x2="551.168" y2="109.667"/>
    <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="646.834" y1="151" x2="739.834" y2="108.001"/>
    <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="646.834" y1="64.334" x2="739.834" y2="105.5"/>
    <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="746.168" y1="105.5" x2="840.834" y2="77.997"/>
    <line fill="#CDCED0" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="848.166" y1="77.997" x2="943.833" y2="97.667"/>
</svg>
```

**CSS**:

```
.black {
  stroke: black;
}
```

and **jQuery**:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("line").addClass("black");
});
```

It seems that whatever comes from `CSS` class overrides existing `SVG` attributes values.